# databuffer += data_str TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "_io.TextIOWrapper") to str

Tags: python, graph, lidar

I am trying to animate my data which are from LIDAR sensor, but I got this error while trying to animate it! May you help the problem, I am quite new for Python programming, thanks a lot!

This is the problem that I got:

> File "C:\Users\cemal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\veritipleriogrenme.py", line 29, in animate     databuffer +=  data_str TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "_io.TextIOWrapper") to str

These is the data set that I try to animate:

```
0.0,0.0
0.0,269.1
0.0,270.3
0.0,271.5
1617.8,265.6
1627.3,266.8
1629.0,268.0
1633.0,269.2
```

type of my data set is string!

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import math
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np
fig=plot.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_ylim(0,2000)
data = np.zeros(360)
theta = np.linspace(0,360, num=360)
l,  = ax.plot([],[])

databuffer = ""
uzaklik = np.zeros(360)
pol = np.linspace(0,360, num=360)
def animate(i):
    global data, databuffer
    data_str = open(r"C:\Users\cemal\OneDrive\Masaüstü\veri2.txt","r")
    databuffer +=  data_str
    aci=np.linspace(0,360, num=360)
    cap=np.zeros(360)
    p_pol=np.linspace(0,360, num=360)
    p_uzaklik=np.zeros(360)
    aci2=np.linspace(0,360, num=360)
    cap=np.zeros(360)
    for x in data_str:
        pol =x.partition(",")[2].rstrip()
        uzaklik =x.split(',')[0]
        try:

            p_pol=float(pol.strip().strip("'"))
            p_uzaklik=float(uzaklik.strip().strip("'"))

            aci=np.append(p_pol)
            cap=np.append(p_uzaklik)
            aci2=[math.radians(i) for i in aci]
            l.set_data(cap, aci2 )
            data_buffer=""

            return l, 

        except ValueError:
            continue

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,interval=10000)
plot.show()
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are running that produces this error? Without seeing what you are doing we can only really guess at what the problem could be.

Comment: That's a bit better, but pasting your code text in the question will help much much more! Just copy and paste it at the end of your question, highlight it all and press the `{}` button to get it formatted nicely.  This lets us copy-paste what you have to quickly see what the issue is.  If I want to try your code now I'd have a lot of typing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` creates a *buffered reader*. there are many kinds of buffered readers; in this case, it is a text buffered reader. The reader itself cannot be treated like a string, BUT, if you tell your code to read the contents, you will get the data type equivalent to the buffered reader (bytes from a BytesIO buffered reader, and string from a TextIOWrapper)

I would read up a bit on buffered readers as it'll definitely come in handy down the line, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

This code also demonstrates how you can use the buffered reader for your purposes (with some changes to variable names to match the variable type better):

```
data_buffer = ""
data_str_wrapper = open(r"C:\Users\cemal\OneDrive\Masaüstü\veri2.txt","r")
try:
    str += data_str_wrapper
except Exception as e:
    print("Can't combine strings and wrappers")
    print(e)
data_buffer += data_str_wrapper.read()
print("Now that i've read the buffer, I can treat it like a string")
print(data_buffer)
```

Essentially, you need to have data_buffer add the *read* version of the wrapper contents, so where you have `databuffer +=  data_str`, you should really be doing `databuffer +=  data_str.read()`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error (in a different scenario).
My solution was to simply wrap the suspect variable of type `_io.TextIOWrapper` with `str()`.